# In BASH convert a string with . in float

Tags: string, bash, floating-point

I have a string that represent a float:

```
echo $NUM
5.03
```

I need to multiply this number for MEGA. If I do it directly:

```
MEGA="1000"
result=$(($NUM*$MEGA))
```

I receive an error:

```
syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".03 * 1000")
```

Comment: use `bc`, and also the search function at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Bash only has integers, no floats. You'll need a tool like `bc` to properly assign the value of `result`:

```
result=$(bc -l <<<"${NUM}*${MEGA}")
```

Or you can use `awk`:

```
result=$(awk '{print $1*$2}' <<<"${NUM} ${MEGA}")
```